# How do I encrypt document via right-click menu in Tails?

Tags: tails, encryption

I don't understand the procedure here. There are some options to choose from to encrypt the file, but then I can't decrypt it because I don't have the password. How do I create a password before I encrypt?

Answer (score 1):

First, create a key:

1. Select Applications->System Tools->Preferences->Passwords and Keys
2. Select File->New and select "PGP Key" and click Continue.
3. Fill in the details of choice and click Create.

Then right-click any file and select "Encrypt" and select the newly created key to encrypt the file.